# Whats the correct way to implement a descriptor?

Tags: python, descriptor

Considering this code: Run on python 3.6

`Bar` assigns the value to the descriptor instance

`Bat` assigns the value to the containing class instance.

Code examples I've seen (and used to my endless frustration) use the `Bar` example. Such as this [site](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-pythondescriptors/index.html)

and from the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html)

As seen from the output using the `Bar` example two instances of a class can't use the same descriptor.

Or am I missing something?

```
class DescriptorA(object):
    value = None
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value

class DescriptorB(object):
    _value = None
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance._value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance._value = value


class Bar(object):
    foo = DescriptorA()
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

class Bat(object):
    foo = DescriptorB()
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo


print('BAR')
a = Bar(1)
print('a', a.foo)

b = Bar(2)
print('b', b.foo)
print('Checking a')
print('a', a.foo)

print('BAT')
c = Bat(3)
print('c', c.foo)

d = Bat(4)
print('d', d.foo)
print('Checking c')
print('c', c.foo)
```

**outputs**

```
BAR
a 1
b 2
Checking a
a 2
BAT
c 3
d 4
Checking c
c 3
```

**UPDATE**

Just wanted to add this. In response to the good answers. When not using descriptors, but still using class attributes. We get different behavior. This is why I made the mistake of using `DescriptorA`  Eg.

```
class Bar(object):
    foo = None
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

class Bat(object):
    foo = None
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo


print('BAR')
a = Bar(1)
print('a', a.foo)

b = Bar(2)
print('b', b.foo)
print('Checking a')
print('a', a.foo)

print('BAT')
c = Bat(3)
print('c', c.foo)

d = Bat(4)
print('d', d.foo)
print('Checking c')
print('c', c.foo)
```

---

```
BAR
a 1
b 2
Checking a
a 1
BAT
c 3
d 4
Checking c
c 3
```

Comment: `a.foo == 2` after `b = Bar(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your use-case how you store the variables.

We have 4 objects, each having their own set of variables:

- The descriptor class
- Instances of the descriptor
- The normal class
- Instances of the normal class

Normally descriptors **instances** are stored in the "normal class" because the descriptor protocol is not invoked when you store the descriptor in the instance. You could also "go meta" and use descriptors on metaclasses or descriptors inside descriptors but let's ignore these for the sake keeping it short and staying sane (it's not really difficult, but probably a bit too broad).

So in case of your `DescriptorA` you store:

- `value = None` in the descriptor class
- `value = ?` in the descriptor instance (at least after calling `__set__` at least once
- `foo = descriptor instance` in the normal class
- nothing in the class instance

In the case of `DescriptorB` you store:

- `_value = None` in the descriptor class
- nothing in the descriptor instance
- `foo = descriptor instance` in the normal class
- `_value = ?` in the instance of your normal class

See the difference? In the first case different instances of your normal class access the same descriptor instance, so everything is shared. In the second case you store everything on the instance of your class and nothing in the descriptor instance so nothing is shared.

Note that your `DescriptorB` seems strange, why store `_value = None` in the descriptor class, when you never use it? Remember that you access the `_value` of your instance of the normal class not the `_value` of your descriptor instance in `__get__`!

As I said before it depends on your use-case which approach to choose. Normally you want to have some shared attributes and some per-instance attributes. But you could also share attributes between all instances of your descriptor and given that you can also access the type of your normal class instance in `__get__` and use `type(instance)` in `__set__` you could also modify class attributes of your normal class.

For example the example in the Python docs:

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating', self.name)
        self.val = val

>>> class MyClass(object):
...     x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
...     y = 5
...
```

They created a descriptor for a **class variable** - deliberately. In that case there is just no "instance" and it doesn't matter if it's shared because a class variable would be shared by instances by default. That means that even if you set the variable on an instance it would change for all other instances.

So you shouldn't really use descriptor instance variables if you don't want it to be shared. However you should use them for everything that should be shared (e.g. the **name** of the attribute, etc.).

Probably also interesting might be the "way" Python looks up attributes. I generally find this image from [this blog](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup) very informative:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, It's confusing because you can't use a descriptor class attribute like you would a normal class attribute

Comment: @JamesSchinner it has nothing to do with "descriptor vs normal class" but with descriptors _being_ class attributes.

Comment: @JamesSchinner I updated the answer a bit. I think the misunderstanding came from the "what is stored where" question. If it needs further clarification let me know. :)

Comment: I selected your answer because it explains how to think about it. Your post makes sense. But if I were Guido. I would make the behavior of `DescriptorA` work like any other class attribute. Eg. point to the class value until the attribute is explicitly set on the instance.

Comment: It actually offers much more freedom the way it is currently. I mean you can decide if you want to set the attribute on the descriptor class (sharing it between all descriptor instances) or on the descriptor instance, the normal class or the instance. There are use-cases for all these cases. I agree that understanding descriptors is nontrivial but once you fully understand what they are capable of - you probably wouldn't want to "cripple" them (by "point to the class attribute") just by making them easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

A descriptor is defined at class level, and there's only one instance of that descriptor in the class. So, in the first descriptor i.e. `DescriptorA`, you're storing the value as a variable on the descriptor and not on the `instance` object. Obviously, that value would be overridden when you instantiate another instance.

Any value you store at the descriptor would remain same for all the instances of the class to which descriptor is assigned. That's why `DescriptorB` works and is the correct way to use the descriptors and not the first one, unless your use case required variables that are supposed to remain the same across instances.

Answer (score 1):

Descriptors are class attributes (and they have to be for the descriptor protocol to work). Being class attributes mean there's one single descriptor instance shared by all instances of the class (and it's subclasses), so what you observe with class `Bar` and `DescriptorA` is the expected behaviour.

It doesn't mean that "two instances of a class can't use the same descriptor (instance)" - they actually do and that's why you have this behaviour - but that you cannot store per-instance values on your descriptor instance, at least not that simply.

One possible solution would be to maintain an `id(instance):instance_value` mapping in your descriptor, ie:

```
class DescriptorA(object):
    def __init__(self, default=None):
        self._values = {}
        self._default = default
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self._values.get(id(instance), self._default)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self._values[id(instance)] = value
```

but this has quite few drawbacks, the first obvious one being that your `_values` dict will not be cleared when an instance is garbage-collected. It might end up eating quite some ram on a long running process...

Edit: the code in your update is **not** using class attributes. Having an eponym class attribute is irrelevant here - the initializer sets a `value` **instance** attribute that shadows the class-level one (which is actually never used in your code snippet).

If you want a meaningfull example with class attributes, use a mutable object and mutate it instead of creating an instance attribute:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    bar = []
...    def __init__(self, baaz):
...        self.baaz = baaz
...        self.bar.append(baaz)
... 
>>> f1 = Foo("foo1")
>>> f1.baaz
'foo1'
>>> f1.bar
['foo1']
>>> f2 = Foo("foo2")
>>> f1.baaz
'foo1'
>>> f2.baaz
'foo2'
>>> f1.bar
['foo1', 'foo2']
>>> f2.bar
['foo1', 'foo2']
>>>
```

Comment: I guess in such a case I would use the `Bat` example. It would clutter the class object though. I updated my post, I think it highlights why it caught me off guard

Comment: @JamesSchinner you're __not__ using class attribute in your "update" section snippet.

Comment: yes because I assign `self.foo = foo` emphasis on `self`. I'm trying to show that `self.foo = foo` when a descriptor is used does get assigned to at the class level.